# How to convert a WMO message of type XML to a JAXB object?

Tags: java, jaxb, mule, mule-component

I am trying to read the WMQ messages that are in XML format in the Queue and convert them to Java JAXB object for further analysis. I have written like this.

[image: Flow]

```
 <wmq:connector name="WMQ" hostName="localhost" port="1414" queueManager="TestMQ" channel="MY_SVRCONN" username="turlapatip@CNSI" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="WMQ"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<mulexml:jaxb-context name="ELIGIBITLITY" packageNames="com.test.jaxb" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
<flow name="mulemqclientFlow">
    <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="test.queue.local.1" connector-ref="WMQ" doc:name="WMQ"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.Class)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer  jaxbContext-ref="ELIGIBITLITY" doc:name="XML to JAXB Object" ignoreBadInput="true"/>
    <logger level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

But I am getting error like

```
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.jms.JMSException: Source was not of a supported type. Valid types are Message, String, Map, InputStream, List, byte[], Serializable or OutputHandler, but was ELIGIBILITY
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageUtils.toMessage(JmsMessageUtils.java:144)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.AbstractJmsTransformer.transformToMessage(AbstractJmsTransformer.java:66)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.transport.wmq.transformers.ObjectToWMQJmsMessage.transformMessage(ObjectToWMQJmsMessage.java:58)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:141)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageTransformer.java:89)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.transformMessage(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1613)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1516)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1490)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1473)
    at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsReplyToHandler.processReplyTo(JmsReplyToHandler.java:90)
    at org.mule.routing.requestreply.AbstractReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier.processReplyTo(AbstractReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier.java:67)
    at org.mule.routing.requestreply.AbstractReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier.process(AbstractReplyToPropertyRequestReplyReplier.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:49)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1...
```

Answer (score 0):

JAXB provides an implementation to transform XML into Java classes that are bound to the XML schema. My rep is not yet where I can comment, but I would ask if the package in the JAXB context declaration contains a JAXB Java binding object (class). The toMessage() method in JmsMessageUtils class takes an object (I'm assuming comes from the JMS queue) and does a series of instanceof checks and the JAXB context declaration is affecting this object possibly because the Java binding object does not exist in the package specified.

Please comment with the objects (Java class names) in the com.test.jaxb package. If the JMS queue is working correctly it's supplying a JMS Message (object) and the JmsMessageUtils is being called to return the Mule message from the XML-JAXB transformer. I expect that the JAXB context was not created and a bound object was not supplied as the object argument into the toMessage() method.

https://github.com/codehaus/mule-git/blob/master/tags/mule-3.0.0-M2/transports/jms/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/jms/JmsMessageUtils.java

Give us the class names in the com.test.jaxb package.